# Strange matrix behaviour in r

Tags: r, matrix

If I do:

```
dim(my_matrix)
[1] 758289    768

typeof(my_matrix)
[1] "double"

max(my_matrix)
[1] 1

my_matrix[my_matrix<=0] = 0.0000001
my_matrix[my_matrix>=1] = 0.9999999

max(my_matrix)
[1] 1
```

I have no explanation for this behavior with smaller handmade matrixes it works without problems.

Comment: I would consider `i1 <- my_matrix <=0; i2 <- my_matrix >=1` before doing the assignment. Once you do the assignment, then the values already got changed.  `my_matrix[i1] <- 0.0000001; my_matrix[i2] <- 0.999999`. It is also possible that `max(my_matrix)` is doing some rounding.  Can you check `1 - max(my_matrix)`

Comment: this results in the same problem

Comment: Are you getting. `1-max(my_matrix)`  equals 0

Comment: 1-max(my_matrix)
[1] 4.461338e-09
since when is max rounding?

Comment: There is some rounding off with big matrix as I tried with a smaller matrix and it is working fine as in your description

Comment: very strange!! is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

If an element is less than 1 by a small amount you could get the behavior you noticed.  The larger the matrix the larger the chance that an element is just a bit less than 1 which would explain why it did not happen for smaller matrices.

```
m <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
m[1,1] <- 1-1e-10
m.original <- m

max(m)
## [1] 1

m[m <= 0] <- 0.0000001
m[m >= 1] <- 0.9999999

max(m)
## [1] 1
```

Note that

```
print(max(m.original), digits = 12)
## [1] 0.9999999999

print(max(m), digits = 12)
## [1] 0.9999999999
```